# How to know the source of Ubuntu 64 or 32 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I have an Ubuntu source on a flash stick and I want to know any way that let's me to know the following with out need to run it. The test computer is Windows 7:

1- the version of Ubuntu.
2- 64 bit or 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can read the version and architecture in the `README.diskdefines` file:

  [image]

  It is a plain textfile which you can open with notepad or so:

  ```
  #define DISKNAME  Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS "Precise Pangolin" - Release i386
  #define TYPE  binary
  #define TYPEbinary  1
  #define ARCH  i386
  #define ARCHi386  1
  #define DISKNUM  1
  #define DISKNUM1  1
  #define TOTALNUM  0
  #define TOTALNUM0  1
  ```
- Also `.disk/info` file, example:

  ```
  Ubuntu-Server 12.04.3 LTS "Precise Pangolin" - Release amd64 (20130820.2)
  ```
- `dists/precise/Release` file (precise is name of the release):

  ```
  Architectures: amd64
  Codename: precise
  Components: main restricted extras
  Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 02:30:54 UTC
  Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
  Label: Ubuntu
  Origin: Ubuntu
  Suite: precise
  Version: 12.04
  MD5Sum:
   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e                0 Release
   efedbc5cc3342ad15ed70f01c49ba17b          1481266 extras/binary-amd64/Packages
   [...]
  ```